# how can I pass info from one method to another in python

Tags: python, class, pyqt4

So I'm a noob to PyQt and to python for that matter. I'm trying to write a simple Qt app that allows you to click a button then display what you entered in the text field in the command prompt, (i know this is ridiculously basic, but I'm trying to learn it) but I can't seem to figure out how to access the textBox attribute from printTexInput() method. so my question is how would you access that value from another method? or is my way of thinking about this completely wrong? any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        textBoxLabel = QtGui.QLabel('Text Input')
        self.textBox = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        okayButton = QtGui.QPushButton("Okay")

        okayButton.clicked.connect(self.printTexInput)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(textBoxLabel, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(textBox, 0, 1)
        grid.addWidget(okayButton, 3, 3)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setGeometry(300,300,250,250)
        self.setWindowTitle("test")
        self.show()

    def printTexInput(self):
        print self.textBox.text()
        self.close()




def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Right now `textBox` is a local variable in the `initUI` method, and it's lost forever when you leave that method.  If you want to store `textBox` on this instance of your class, you need to say `self.textBox = QtGui.QLineEdit()` instead.  Then in `printTextInput` you can call `print self.textBox.text()` instead.

Comment: @charleyc you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I tried that, and it outputted: NameError: global name 'textBox' is not defined

Comment: Make sure you're calling `self.textBox.text()` and not just `textBox.text()`.

Comment: first off I appreciate your help. I updated the posted code to reflect what you are talking about. which I've also tried running, and it does nothing, just prints out that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now `textBox` is a local variable in the `initUI` method, and it's lost forever when you leave that method.  If you want to store `textBox` on this instance of your class, you need to say `self.textBox = QtGui.QLineEdit()` instead.  Then in `printTextInput` you can call `print self.textBox.text()` instead.

Comment: I tried that, and it outputted: NameError: global name 'textBox' is not defined.

Comment: The line `grid.addWidget(textBox, 0, 1)` needs to be `grid.addWidget(self.textBox, 0, 1)`.

Comment: you my friend are awesome! thank you. you have solved it! :) thank you so much.